# Nesting .NET Core appsettings.json appsettings.development.json and appsettings.release.json

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have two asp.net core console apps.

First one has appsettings json files as shown below.

[image: appsettings json files nested]

As you can see they are nicely nested.

The second core project is also console project. I have added appsettings json files but they are nested.

What am I missing

[image: appsettings json files not nested]

Comment: I am running into same problem. Please add more relevant tags to it. I don't know exactly what but this might be a setting in VS itself. The reason? I just created brand new ASP.NET Core 3.1 app on two different machines each with VS 2019. The only diff between the two being on one, its Community Edition and on the other Enterprise. The one on community edition nested the appsettings as I expected without me doing anything. On Enterprise edition, it leaves them flat just like your pic above.

Comment: I just copied the same solution to other computer verified that the same proj shows appsettings properly nested when the project is opened in VS 2019 community edition.  When opened in VS 2019 Enterprise edition (on separate computer), the appsettings show as flat files as shown in yoiur second image. It has to do with something in VS itself

Answer (score 7):

You can edit the project file to add this element:

```
<ItemGroup>
        <None Update="appsettings.Development.json">
            <DependentUpon>appsettings.json</DependentUpon>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="appsettings.Release.json">
            <DependentUpon>appsettings.json</DependentUpon>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
```

result:

[image]

Don't forget to reload your project if you edit it outside of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue in my console application.

I noticed the following string in my project file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

I changed it to

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">
```

After I saved the project, the settings files became nested.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"> also causes nesting

Answer (score -1):

Add a new appsettings.json file in the the same project and then rename like appsettings.envname.json
it will be added as nested file to appsettings.json in solution.

[image]